# When to do Nashorn over Java Hooks?

Tags: hook, nashorn

I have a java application that does text processing.

Nashorn could be used to add customization just like hooks.  So When should I use Nashorn and when should I use hooks? (assuming language doesn't matter)

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to write your hooks assuming java lambdas.  This would allow Nashorn functions or Java functions to be used for your hooks.  If you direct your question to nashorn-dev with specifics you will get more specific details.